# Prevent uninstallation of Cydia tweaks

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia

I have GuizmoDNS installed on my iPhone (it can lock in DNS settings for WiFi and Cellular data). This is great for when my kids browse the web, as it can block most inappropriate sites, and the settings themselves are password protected.

But removing the tweak itself is an easy way around this. Is there any way to password protect the removal of Cydia tweaks?

I would very much like to **not** have to password protect Cydia itself.

Comment: Manually installing the tweak without using `dpkg` or Cydia will do the trick. Cydia won't even know about it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is as mentioned by @Andrew, according to me there are two other possible things you can do:

- install iAppLock and lock Cydia so nothing can be changed at all with in Cydia
- install GuestMode and disable Cydia so that, you can see it but can't open it